# SharePoint Communication Site change font one type for Headers and another type for everything else?

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-collection, style.css, font

I have a request for the Communication site Headers and Navigation to be one font family/type, and all other text on the pages be another font family/type.  Where does one go to edit this information?

thanks,

Kev

Answer (score 0):

Please note that it is **not** supported to change the font family for **modern experience** in SharePoint online since [customizing mater page is not supported](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations-customize-sites#whats-not-supported-on-modern-team-sites).

See a UserVoice post here: [Allow customizing fonts in “Modern” pages.](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/34394050-allow-customizing-fonts-in-modern-pages)

For classic experience, you need to [create a master page preview file](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-create-a-master-page-preview-file-in-sharepoint) in SharePoint Online, then create your Font schemes. Additional reference for classic experience if case you need it: [Color palettes and fonts in SharePoint.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/color-palettes-and-fonts-in-sharepoint#font-schemes)